# Leaflet reverse geocode

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geocoding, reverse-geocoding, esri-leaflet

What I want is to use Leaflet maps + function where I can pass Lat/Lng and receive a text message with address.

I am trying to use esri plugin, however I am doing something wrong.
At the moment I am abke to get the address inseide of function but I do not know how to properly pass it to variable.

Here is my code:

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([40.725, -73.985], 7);

L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);

var geocodeService = L.esri.Geocoding.geocodeService();

map.on('click', function(e) {
  geocodeService.reverse().latlng(e.latlng).run(function(error, result) {
    L.marker(result.latlng).addTo(map).bindPopup(result.address.Match_addr).openPopup();
  });
});

var message;

message = geocodeService.reverse().latlng([40.725, -73.985]).run(function(error, result) {
  //alert(result.address.Match_addr); //this alert works here ok and can retur addrress
  return result.address.Match_addr;
});

//this alert won't work, why I can get the address here outside the function
alert(message);
```

and here is full example:
https://jsfiddle.net/5aq6z1vL/

How to use geocoder as a function like:

```
var address = convertToAddress([40.725, -73.985]);

function convertToAddress(]lat,lon])
{
  // here return address after geocoding
}
```

Answer (score 1):

just you can change the function by :

```
var geocodeService = L.esri.Geocoding.geocodeService();


geocodeService.reverse().latlng([36.2933693, 7.9388789]).run(function (error, result) {
  if (error) {
    return;
  }

  L.marker(result.latlng).addTo(map).bindPopup(result.address.Match_addr).openPopup();
});
```

Comment: Simple Tip : Just add code format to this line of code var geocodeService = L.esri.Geocoding.geocodeService();; thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the `message` will get filled with the HTTP response from the `run` function.

Because the `run` function takes some time to execute the `alert(message)` will be executed before the run function finishes.

Here is a fiddle of what **could** resolve your issue: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/05drwh9q/)

**EDIT:**

Ok, so what you're looking for is `Promises`.
Your code needs to wait for the plugin to fetch the address.
Unfortunatelly, I don't know how to do this with vanilla JS, so I've imported jQuery (to use the methods `$.when` and `then` and the object `$.Deferred`).

Here is the new [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k7ca65z4/1/)

If you need this in vanilla JS I can look into Promises in vanilla JS.

Comment: thannk you, this partially helps. But how to use this geocodins as a function like: var address = convertToAddress([40.725, -73.985]);

function convertToAddress(]lat,lon])
{
  // here return address after geocoding
}

Comment: comments are breaking the code, so please take a look at modified question

Comment: Hello, unfortunalelly not. I still can't get decoded address in variable.
Could you please take a look at this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/c71ndrhv/1/ Lin 16

Comment: Everytime you want to decode an address and use your variable you have to do this: 
var result= convertToAddress([lat,lon]);
$.when(result).done(function(r){
 result=r;
  //write the rest of the code that uses the address here
})